# Очередь проверок не прошла мой аудит

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок, аудит

Закрытие вопросов по желанию левой пятки довело нас до того, что для аудита выбираются совершенно неподходящие вопросы.

Вопрос: [Linux скрипт на создание папки с указанным пользователем именем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466499/). Для тех, кто не видит удаленные вопросы:

---

> Какие команды нужно дописать чтобы дать возможность пользователю указывать имя создаваемой папки через терминал?

[linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) [bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)

---

Я видел, что вопрос давно закрыт и удален, но принципиально [нажал «оставить открытым»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/46313), потому что считаю этот вариант верным. Разумеется, если бы ответ не был удален, я сразу отредактировал бы его:

> Какой командой можно создать папку через терминал (консоль)?

Вопрос элементарный и сформулирован плохо, но это нормальный вопрос новичка. Вопрос можно было бы переформулировать и ответить. Чтобы ответ не был совсем тривиальным, добавить про возможности, о которых знает не каждый, например `mkdir -p make/intermediate/directories`, `mkdir -m 0600 restricted`.

> Все уже есть (mkdir) – avp 15 ноя в 9:35

А вот и ответ, правда он в комментарии. :(

> Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос уже имеет решение. – Yuri Glushenkov 15 ноя в 9:37

Что?! Вы серьезно?! И ещё четверо плюсанули комментарий, наверняка из очереди проверок. С каких пор «имеет решение» — это признак плохого вопроса?

> удален пользователем Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ 15 ноя в 16:45

Nicolas, зачем вы его удалили? Неужели вопрос был настолько опасен для сайта, что для срочного удаления требовалось вмешательство модератора? Его теперь даже восстановить нельзя.

Comment: Комментарий по статусу: это не баг, фича так работает. Чтобы не попадалось спорных вопросов, нужно точнее закрывать. Комментарии конкретных участников вообще не могут быть багом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт правильно, т.к. его нужно конкретизировать. Я перечитал его 5 раз и так и не понял, что хочет автор. Комментарий Юрия, видимо, автоматический и генерируется на кнопку «закрыть как дубликат». Возможно, Юрий предложил какой-то вопрос дубликатом, но в закрытии сыграла другая причина — которая реально подходит.

Не вижу причин переоткрывать вопрос, как и удалить, собственно.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Лично я закрыл этот вопрос из-за совершенно непонятной формулировки. Его стоит восстановить и исправить (если кто-то точно понял, что имел ввиду автор)

Comment: @PashaPash avp понял. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не факт, что то, что понял avp имеет отношение к тому, что имел в виду автор

Comment: @ixSci: В любом случае, лучше ответить на исправленный ответ, если даже он не вполне соответствует замыслу автора. Если автору нужен ответ, он вернётся и подправит. Если автору ответ больше не нужен и он не вернётся, то лучше иметь ответ, чем не иметь его.

Comment: Кстати, такого автоматического комментария нет. На дубликат создается совершенно иной комментарий.